# Set to checked CheckBoxes with Script

Tags: javascript, html

everyone I am trying to put a checkbox as checked when its parameter in my database is set to true and unchecked when it is set to false.
For that, I am using a script because I already have the info from my database in my html code.
Well, the parameters are all working great, but the checkbox don´t appear. Could someone help me?

```
<div class="form-group">

                  <label>Presentar:</label>

                    <script>
                        console.log(document.getElementById('checkboxoutput').textContent);
                        if(document.getElementById('checkboxoutput').textContent==="True"){
                            console.log("Entro a true");
                            let x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                            x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                            x.setAttribute("name", "presentar");
                            x.setAttribute("value", "true");
                            x.setAttribute("checked", "true");
                            document.body.appendChild(x);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("Entro a false");
                            let x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                            x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                            x.setAttribute("name", "presentar");
                            x.setAttribute("value", "true");
                            x.setAttribute("checked", "false");
                            document.body.appendChild(x);
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>
```

As I said before, I put some log messages to make sure that the condition is true or false, and it works fine.
The second point is that I don´t know where to appendchild, but the Input has to be inside the div class form-group.

Answer (score 0):

To show your checkbox, you can give an id to your div. Then you put the checkbox in and it will appear.

I hope that my answer will be clear to you and that it will have helped you.